# Modal is blocking everything on my webpage

Tags: html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

hii i am using bootstrap modal in my word-press website.

When i am trying to call modal it is blocking everything on my webpage
code i have written for calling a modal is

Open Modal

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

output is
[image]

please let me know what is the problem.

Comment: That's probably a z-index issue. Without CSS It's hard to tell. Try to use a high z-index on modal content: `.modal-content {z-index: 20000;}`

Comment: Make sure your modal html is in a top-level position as specified in the docs http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: Do you have only one modal or multiple modals on same page?